# change or move the position of the popup react-leaflet

Tags: css, reactjs, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

My popup from the marker is overlapping, making it partially visible. I need to move the popup above.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
<Marker
  draggable={draggable}
  eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
  position={position}
  ref={markerRef}
>
  <Popup>
    <span onClick={toggleDraggable}>
      {draggable && <Button>Click Here</Button>}
    </span>
  </Popup>
</Marker>
```

I also tried access the popup component, but that breaks the popup.

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: On the [docs page](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker/) it shows correctly above the marker. Can you check if there are any errors in the console or anything?

Comment: @Conman_123 Nope, No error

Comment: Edited my answer with a different option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack to get around it:

```
.leaflet-popup {
    padding-bottom: 30px; /* adjust as you see fit */
}
```